# Is it possible to inherit GitHub secrets and pass additional secrets as well?

Tags: github-actions

When calling a GitHub workflow, is it possible to use both "inherit" and also pass additional GitHub secrets?

E.g.

```yaml
jobs:
  call-workflow:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/called-workflow.yml
    secrets:
      inherit: true
      ADDITIONAL_SECRET: ${{ secrets.ADDITIONAL_SECRET }}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it? And given that [_"all secrets the calling workflow has access to"_](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsecretsinherit) are already inherited, what else do you think there is to pass?

Comment: I think you can only choose between repository and organization secrets

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have not tried it yet. I am deliberately posting questions before trying out things. (i) it takes me little time, (ii) it helps build a public Q&A of already-answered questions (will help future students and LLMs), and (iii) I can look up the question in the future if I bump into the same issue again.

Comment: about "what else do you think there is to pass?" - I have a use case whereby I want to rename a secret.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Using the [GitHub Actions for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-github-actions) extension, I have tried this approach:

```yaml
secrets:
  inherit: true
  VERCEL_PROJECT_ID: "..."
```

I got this error:

> Invalid secret, inherit is not defined in the referenced workflow.

Then, I tried this approach:

```yaml
secrets: "inherit"
secrets:
  VERCEL_PROJECT_ID: "prj_1hHpDxBdgIZYX1MSlwrXWFpMFOlm"
```

And for this, I have gotten this error:

> `secrets` is already defined

There's also this GitHub discussion that suggest that the choice between inherited secrets and explicit secrets is an either/ or kind of thing:

https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/23107#discussioncomment-5707861